# Find 2 primes with the following property

Tags: prime-numbers, square-numbers

```
Find 2 primes that are 1 more than a square number.  If this cannot be done, prove that it is impossible.
```

I have devised the equation:

```
x^2 + 1 = k, where k is a prime number
```

I have the solution:
All prime numbers are odd, except 2.  So, let's try 2.

When k = 2:

```
x^2 + 1 = 2
x^2 = 1
x = ±1, so 2 has this property
```

Rearranging the equation:

```
x^2 = k-1
```

As k is odd for all prime values other than 2, k-1 is even.  The square root of an even number is an even number so x must be even.  So, let's try out a few values of x:

When x=0:

```
0+1=k
k=1, which isn't prime
```

When x=2:

```
4+1=k
k=5, which is prime
```

Now we have found 2 primes that have this property.

I know I have technically solved the question, but I would like to know if there is a more elegant solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks fine.  It's a problem that calls for examples, and you provided examples.  Side note:  it is not known whether or not there are infinitely many primes of the form $n^2+1$, though this is conjectured to be true.

Comment: $17, 37, 101$ are also examples, but you were only asked for two.  https://oeis.org/A002496 has a list of examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question asked you to provide 2 examples, and you did! Your solution seems fine. As mentioned in the comments, there is not yet a general solution for all primes of the form $n^2+1$.